# 1 select_tag multiple database columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, html-select

**The background is this:** 
our end users are not the most tech suave so we try to make it as simple as possible for these guys.

We have a form where a reviewer will look at a record and qualify it. This data goes into multiple columns:

example: 
Was it a lead? 
based on the answer it'll bring yup 2 select tags that'll go to the following database column:

yes:

```
<td><%= f.select :reasoninquiry_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@inquiryreasons, 'id', 'reason', @lead.reasoninquiry_id), { include_blank: true }  %></td>
```

No:

```
<%= f.select :nonleadaction_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@nonleadactions, 'id', 'non_lead_action_type', @lead.nonleadaction_id), { include_blank: true } %>
```

We give our end users the opportunity to update this if they want. And here is where it gets tricky.

Currently our app is written in PHP and we use 1 select box and it sends data to 2 different tables, depending on what was selected.

Is there a way I can do this in rails?

To be clear what we'd want is 1 select box that will be able to submit data to 2 database columns, depending on what was selected. I'd want one select tag for 2 collections.

The select box would show options for both @inquiryreasons (which would submit to :reasoninquiry_id if one of them is selected) and @nonleadactions (which would submit to :nonleadactions_id if one of them is selected.)

Comment: how does your database.yml look like

Comment: I'm using sqlite3 for local database. do you want me to copy it in?

Comment: oh no, I thought u had an external db connection as well.

Comment: nope, just local right now. I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to do this, but I figure if it's possible in php something could be figured out in ruby.

Comment: so finally the chosed option value is to be stored to 2 tables?

Comment: @nithin 1 table, 2 different columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58398/discussion-between-nithin-and-steve-q).